# what exactly do I need to make my pc an ssh server and connect to it?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I tried to create ssh server on my pc. It connects well on LAN but over internet it does not. I have tried everything that I can. I can connect to azure server from pc though.

I am running arch linux.
sshd is running.

What are the things I need to make it work?

Comment: Is your PC directly connected to the Internet with a public IP address? If not, you're going to need to arrange port forwarding - probably in your router. (But if you're on CG NAT you'll need to discuss options with your ISP.)

Answer (score 2):

Based on:

> It connects well on LAN but over internet it does not.

And:

> I can connect to azure server from pc though

...it sounds as though you have not configured your *router* to accept incoming connections to the port that runs `ssh` (standard is 22, but I use a different port for my server).

This of course is hard to describe, because there are tons of different router manufacturers out there.

Comment: I’d add that you can open a port either using your router’s interface, or using an upnp portmapper such as yaup

Comment: thanks, yes the port forwarding seems the problem. But i use ISP internet(hotspot from mobile). So i need to open a port for isp. Is that right??

Comment: Actually, it’s your mobile that needs to forward the port. maybe try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705448/can-you-port-forward-with-an-android-device